# JHipster v7.1.0: Docker compose sub-generator fails, cant fins installed docker compose

Tags: jhipster

I have describe my applications and entities including the docker deployment in a jdl file and when running '**jhipster jdl myjdlfile**' the apps and entities are generated without error but the docker compose subgenerator fails when the following message;

```js
INFO! Generating 1 deployment.
INFO! Generating deployment docker-compose in a new parallel process
✔ Docker is installed

Found .yo-rc.json config file...
Docker Compose 1.6.0 or later is not installed on your computer.
         Read https://docs.docker.com/compose/install/

  Welcome to the JHipster Docker Compose Sub-Generator 
Files will be generated in folder: /<remove intentionally>/docker-compose

Checking Docker images in applications directories...
ls: no such file or directory: /<remove intentionally>/gateway/target/jib-cache
ls: no such file or directory: /<remove intentionally>/backend/target/jib-cache
    force ../gateway/.yo-rc.json
    force ../backend/.yo-rc.json
    force .yo-rc.json
   create docker-compose.yml
   create README-DOCKER-COMPOSE.md
   create central-server-config/application.yml

No change to package.json was detected. No package manager install will be executed.

WARNING! Docker Compose configuration generated, but no Jib cache found
If you forgot to generate the Docker image for this application, please run:
To generate the missing Docker image(s), please run:
  ./mvnw -ntp -Pprod verify jib:dockerBuild in /<remove intentionally>/gateway
  ./mvnw -ntp -Pprod verify jib:dockerBuild in /<remove intentionally>/backend

You can launch all your infrastructure by running : docker-compose up -d
Congratulations, JHipster execution is complete!
Sponsored with ❤️  by @oktadev.
INFO! Generator docker-compose child process exited with code 0
Congratulations, JHipster execution is complete!
```

If I build the projects and run in each project '**./mvnw -ntp -Pprod verify jib:dockerBuild**' everything gets build and I can start all applications with docker-compose.

The part that I do not understand is why it says that "**Docker Compose 1.6.0 or later is not installed on your computer**"? Since I do have docker-compose installed v2.0.0-beta.6

I have;

- Docker version 20.10.7, build f0df350
- Docker Compose version v2.0.0-beta.6
- openjdk 11.0.11 2021-04-20
  OpenJDK Runtime Environment AdoptOpenJDK-11.0.11+9 (build 11.0.11+9)
  OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM AdoptOpenJDK-11.0.11+9 (build 11.0.11+9, mixed mode)
- JHipster v7.1.0
- Node v16.5.0
- npm v7.20.1

The deployment part of the jdl file is;

```
deployment {
   deploymentType docker-compose
   appsFolders [gateway, backend]
   dockerRepositoryName "carestra"
   serviceDiscoveryType eureka
}
```

Comment: Your question about docker compose version checking: as always when you don't understand something, check the code https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/blob/main/generators/docker-compose/index.js#L55-L76
You see 2 things: 1. you can skip this check (probably using --skip-checks) 2. The check is implemented using `docker-compose -v` . From my PC, `docker -v` prints
`Docker version 20.10.7, build f0df350` while `docker-compose -v`prints `docker-compose version 1.29.2, build 5becea4c`. You say "Docker Compose version v2.0.0-beta.6", how did you get this?

Comment: Thanks @gmarziou ... it seems to be a bug then, since on Mac OSX 10.15.7 using docker-desktop v3.5.2(66501) I get  
**docker -v** => Docker version 20.10.7, build f0df350
**docker --version** => Docker version 20.10.7, build f0df350
**docker-compose -v** => unknown shorthand flag: 'v' in -v
**docker-compose --version** => Docker Compose version v2.0.0-beta.6

Comment: It seems to be a bug in docker-desktop for MacOSX, since if I disable v2 (docker-desktop->preferences->Experimental Features-> uncheck 'Use Docker Compose V2') **docker-compose --version** => docker-compose version 1.29.2, build 5becea4c **docker-compose -v** => docker-compose version 1.29.2, build 5becea4c ..... How to I set --skip-checks for docker-compose in a JDL?

Comment: Docker Desktop for Windows/Mac includes Compose along with other Docker apps, so most Windows/Mac users do not need to install Compose separately. I guess this checking is probably obsolete for recent versions of  docker. `--skip-checks`is global (not only for docker-compose) so you could run it as `jhipster jdl myjdlfile --skip-checks` or if you want to do it inside JDL add `skipChecks true` in `application.config`